# How to iterate array with vivewports with it tests and beforeeach

Tags: javascript, cypress

I run into issue with viewport issue and I didn't find the solution yet.

```
describe('Tests', function () {
beforeEach(function () {
});

viewports.forEach((viewport) => {
    it.only(`Test: ${viewport}`, function () {
        cy.viewportAdjust(viewport);
    })})})
```

I used `cy.viewportAdjust(viewport);`in my test and it works, however I wish to move `cy.viewportAdjust(viewport);` to `beforeEach` section but for tests it uses last value of viewportsArray

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what `cy.viewportAdjust()` does, as that looks to be a custom function. If the function simply calls `cy.viewport()` or updates the viewport, the following will work. Additionally, with not knowing what the values in `viewport` are, I can't give an exact complete answer, but the general idea is that you can pass in your viewportWidth or viewportHeight in the `it()` block.

```js
viewports.forEach((viewport) => {
    it.only(`Test: ${viewport}`, { viewportWidth: viewport }, function () {
        cy.viewportAdjust(viewport);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Im going to answer this question exactly how you asked. But I would not suggest doing it this way though without seeing everything that you are trying to do I don't have 100% confidence in this statement.

```
describe('Tests Viewports', () => {
  const viewports = ['iphone-6', 'ipad-2', 'ipad-mini'] //insert viewport you wish to test here
  let x = 0
  beforeEach( () => {
    cy.viewport(viewports[x])
    //Do a thing
    x += 1
  })
  viewports.forEach( (viewport) => {
    it(`Tests: ${viewport}`, () => {
      cy.log(viewport)
    })
  })
})
```

I would instead suggest removing the beforeEach block and putting your code within the it block.